# Apache MaxClient Setting for 256 GB RAM with mpm_prefork module

Tags: php, apache, multiprocessing

I want to increase MaxClient for Apache server with mpm_prefork module. I am running only webserver in the dedicated server with 256 GB RAM. I don't run any other program in the server.

I am running HTTP webservice API in the server which is developed using PHP which will be called 1000 times in a second

I am running CentOS 7

Server Specification
Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v3 Hexa-Core Haswell,
RAM 256 GB DDR4 ECC RAM,
Hard Drive2 x 480 GB SSD(Software-RAID 1),
Connection 1 Gbit/s

1) What is the maximum value that I can use for MaxClient? Can i use 1000?

2) I am running Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS). I could't find any file to change MaxClient. Where can I change it? /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file doesn't have MaxClient setting. Also /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf file also doesn't have MaxClient setting

I am new to Apache server. Please help me to do it. I tried 2 days but not find any solution

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not included in the default config that comes with CentOS 7. Add a block like this near the top of your httpd.conf, before the `LoadModule` directives (this is what I use for a lower spec server):

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
        StartServers        8
        MinSpareServers     5
        MaxSpareServers    20
        ServerLimit       256
        MaxRequestWorkers 200
        MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000
</IfModule>
```

`MaxClients` has been renamed `MaxRequestWorkers` in Apache 2.4. I keep `ServerLimit` a bit higher than that, since `ServerLimit` cannot be changed by a restart, but `MaxRequestWorkers` can. `ServerLimit` sets the maximum value for `MaxRequestWorkers`. So putting `ServerLimit` a bit higher gives you room to increase `MaxRequestWorkers` in an emergency without cutting clients off.

The above is what I use on my server. With the spec that you have I'm sure a value of 1000 for `MaxRequestWorkers` will be fine. Perhaps put `ServerLimit` at 1200.

See the [documentation for ServerLimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit).

You will want to increase the other values too. Perhaps 40 for `StartServers`, 25 for `MinSpareServers` and 100 for `MaxSpareServers`.

I like to keep `MaxConnectionsPerChild` at 1000 so that if there are any memory leaks they will not cause big trouble. I suggest you keep the same value.

Please [research all the directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#page-header) and make your own decisions. Hopefully the above will get you started.

Putting it all together, I suggest you use:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
        StartServers        40
        MinSpareServers     25
        MaxSpareServers    100
        ServerLimit       1200
        MaxRequestWorkers 1000
        MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000
</IfModule>
```

Keep an eye on the server resources once you have it in place though, and the server is being used. You can probably make use of significantly higher values than this.

**Another Important Issue**

I strongly recommend you disable the `LoadModule` directives for any modules you are not using (just comment them out). This will significantly lower the memory footprint of each server process and allow you to run more of them. There are many modules loaded in the default config that you won't need. Go through them one by one and Google for what they do. This will improve the efficiency of your resource usage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. currently using LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so in the  /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf. You mean to disable this also?

Comment: No, you need that. What I mean is, at the top of your httpd.conf you will find many many LoadModule directives. I have disabled around 30 or more on my server and you can probably do the same. They each add different functionality to the server, and most of it you won't need. Each bit of extra functionality adds memory usage to every server process. It takes time to go through them all, but is worth it. You have to tune Apache to make it work really efficiently and that is a big part of it. Especially when resource usage is so important for you.

Comment: You might want to upvote my answer now you have enough reputation to do so, using the up arrow at the top left of it :)

Comment: i will create a file like 10-prefork.conf inside /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/ directory and add above configuration because the main httpd.conf file include all conf file inside that directory.  is that also ok?

Comment: The usual place to have these directives is at the top of the main httpd.conf, but if you prefer to do that then I think it should be fine.